# seleccion de input radio para apuntar a un formulario

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

como puede acceder a un formulario seleccionando inputs radios?

tengo este ejemplo pero no me funciona

```
<input name="tabs" checked type="radio" data-target="#fisica">Persona Física
<input name="tabs" type="radio" data-target="#moral">Persona Moral
<input name="tabs" type="radio" data-target="#extranjero">Proveedor Extranjero

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="fisica" class="tab-pane active schedule-pane">
   <form  id="personaFisica">
      <input type="text" name="prueba">aaaa
   </form>
 </div>
  <div id="moral" class="tab-pane active schedule-pane">
   <form  id="personaMoral">
      <input type="text" name="prueba">aaaa
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: es decir la hacer click en un radio button deseas mostrar el formulario especifico ?

Comment: siiii @Tegito123

Comment: Has intentado ponerle data-toggle="tab" a los radio y ponerlos todos dentro de un div class="nav nav-tabs"

Comment: noo estoy usando adminlte

Comment: porque no usas el ejemplo que tiene bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: ya lo tenia haci pero mi jefe anda enojado y lo quiere forzosamente con radio

Comment: ahuevo.. que puto que lo haga el

Comment: mira aqui tendrias una base...http://jsfiddle.net/Lpow6dq5/19/

Comment: ahora si te fijas al hacer click  primero en persona fisica y luego en moral se ve los dos form.. debes controlar ello.. pero en escencia es la idea.. hay muchas formas de hacerlo !!

Comment: pero que como muestras el tab en tu js?

Comment: mira esto aqui tiene algo similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978224/using-radio-buttons-for-tab-control-using-bootstrap

Comment: este estoy usando  $(this).tab('show'); pero no la muestra

Comment: deja lo intento hay diferencia

Comment: ya quedo deja la respuesta abajo para darte tus puntos me acabas de salvar muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Agrega **ID** a cada **radio** y agregas lo siguiente:

```
    $('#radioFisica').click(function(){
      $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
      $('#fisica').addClass('active');
    });

  $('#radioMoral').click(function(){
      $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
      $('#moral').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: si llega a la funcion pero no muestra la tab

Comment: intente con este tambien  $(this).tab('show'); pero no lo muestra

Comment: ¿Te muestra un mensaje de error la consola?

Comment: puse un console para ver si enteaba en el if y si llegaba pero de ahi no funciona $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
      $('#fisica').addClass('active');

Comment: ¿Si tienes cargado el js de bootstrap? https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/

Comment: si compa me imagino que es por la plantilla de adminlte trae diferentes formas de llamar creo, por que en la version pasada en el js agregaba la funcion $('#tabs_1').tab('show'); con el mismo codigo html y me funcionaba.